# prestashop 1.6.1.17 making http to https, cannot open front office and back office

Tags: https, prestashop-1.6

I am new to prestashop. I currentlly got the ssl certificate and change the http to https, When I change this on backend office
 [image]

At this point I can log in to back office. and the url is green.

[image]

Then the front page is not working 
It says redirect many times.
[image]

Then I changed the .htaccess file added this

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://buyfood.co.nz/$1 [R,L]
```

Then I cannot even log in to backend office.

Please help me, Thank you!!!

Comment: Is port 443 accessible/open? Can you check apache log?

Comment: @sadlyblue sorry, I just saw your reply. Do i need to add the RewriteRule for each .htaccess file?

Comment: did you found a solution?